# cookies not deleted in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have three cookies compare1,compare2 and compare3. After the user clicks on the close button i want to delete the cookie and then get the cookies which are set either compare2 or compare3 or compare1. I am using javascript for the same, but my cookies are not deleted. Here is my code:

```
  $('#srchresult #frmCompare a.close').click( function() {
   var parentName = $(this).parent().attr('id');
   var parentId=  parentName.replace('dvPkg','');       
   document.cookie = 'compare'+parentId + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
        alert(document.cookie);
        var username1=getCookie("compare1");
        var username2=getCookie("compare2");
        var username3=getCookie("compare3");

        if (username1!=null && username1!="")
  {
  alert(username1);
  }
   if (username2!=null && username2!="")
  {
  alert(username2);
  }
   if (username3!=null && username3!="")
  {
  alert(username3);
  }
});
```

Inspite of deleting the cookie, I am still getting the cookies in the alert. I want to delete the cookies without refreshing the page and get the remaining two cookies.

I am not setting the domain or path when creating the cookie. I want to delete the cookie without refreshing the page. I am creating the cookie using php

```
  $cookie = array( 'name' => 'compare' . $noOfItem, 'value' => $noOfItem . '^' . $postId . '^' . $postType . '^' . $return_result['deal_title'] . '^' . $return_result['img_filename'] . '^' . $postcompareCountry, 'expire' => '0', ); 

$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

Comment: How are the cookies created? Do they have a domain or path specified? If so you need to specify the same domain and path when deleting.

Comment: Creation of cookie depends upon your path and domain so as deletion .Thus kindly tell us how you are creating cookie..

Comment: I am not setting the domain or path when creating the cookie. I want to delete the cookie without refreshing the page. I am creating the cookie using php  $cookie = array(
                'name' => 'compare' . $noOfItem,
                'value' => $noOfItem . '^' . $postId . '^' . $postType . '^' . $return_result['deal_title'] . '^' . $return_result['img_filename'] . '^' . $postcompareCountry,
                'expire' => '0',
            );

            $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);

Comment: Please Edit your question and put above thing there ...if you are not setting the path then cookie created will be accessible only in the scope of that page only .

Comment: getCookie is not js function,

Comment: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a 'path' to your cookie. For example:

```
document.cookie = 'cookie2=yet another test; expires=Fri, 27 Jul 2001 02:47:11 UTC; path=/';
```

The path represents the relative path in your website which the cookie will be readable. path=/ means it'll be readable in your whole website. path=/common/ means it'll be readable only in /common/ folder (and its subfolders)

Here is nice tutorial on **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie)** about cookies:-

**UPDATE :-**

While Creating Cookie try to add path also :-

```
 $cookie = array( 'name' => 'compare' . $noOfItem, 'value' => $noOfItem . '^' . $postId . '^' . $postType . '^' . $return_result['deal_title'] . '^' . $return_result['img_filename'] . '^' . $postcompareCountry, 'expire' => '0','path' => '/' );
```

you can check out [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) also :-

Comment: I tried your reply but my cookie is deleted only on page refresh. I don't want to refresh the page.

Comment: Can you show me your set_cookie($cookie) function ...May be then i can help

Comment: I have already added it in my question above. I am setting the cookie via php